# How to change file extention of every file in directory unix/linux

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have a directory of 5,000 files. All these files end with an extention of `.xml` I'd like to change that and have them all end with `.txt`

How can I accomplish this in linux/mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If available in your shell, `rename` is one option that is quick and easy:

```
rename .xml .txt *.xml
```

So to demonstrate, let's use a loop to make 500 files, rename them, and then delete them.

```
for i in $(seq 500); do touch document_${i}.xml; done
ls document*.xml
rename .xml .txt *.xml
ls document*.txt
rm -f document*.txt
ls document*.txt
```

Comment: I don't believe the 'rename' program is included in mac and some linux distros

Comment: @arabian_albert this isn't a groundbreaking question that can't be easily solved with the search ;)

Comment: I just installed rename on the remote rhe machine I was using, no biggie. Thanks for your help